# Unexpected token while creating a dict with another dict in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am trying to learn javascript on my own and on one of the simple programs i am stuck at this :

```
var _c = {RESPONSE:'reponse'};
```

now when i try to use this dict to create another dict (as a value) it works

```
var d = {'bla': _c.RESPONSE};
```

but when I try to use a dict value as a key in another dict its throws Unexpected token error

```
var d = {_c.RESPONSE :'bla'}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

I am not sure what is the problem with the above code.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is straight forward. It's telling you that there's a syntax error.

According to Javascript syntax, an object declaration looks like below: ([source](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/grammar14.html), with a few changes. Look at the comments below.)

```
ObjectLiteral ⇒  { }  |  { FieldList }
FieldList     ⇒  LiteralField  |  FieldList , LiteralField
LiteralField  ⇒  ObjectKey : AssignmentExpression
ObjectKey     ⇒  Identifier | NumericLiteral | StringLiteral
```

.. where `Identifier` is [defined here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables). Identifiers can not contain dots in them. So, clearly, you are violating the grammar/syntax of the language.

---

From what I understand, you'd like to set the key according to the value of some variable. In that case, you the square-bracket notation.

```
var d = {}
d[_c.RESPONSE] = 'bla';
```

Comment: as per your response even this
    var d = {'bla': _c.RESPONSE};
should be an error but its not. What happens here

Comment: Oh i get it. The right is allowed to be an expression. Got it.

Comment: About your first comment: Good catch. The "Identifier" should actually be: " (Identifier | StringLiteral | NumericLiteral )". I'll edit my answer to reflect this one. That source I linked to is incorrect.